# checking that you hit a tile with a player

Tags: javascript

how would I go about adding collision to blocks so that when a player goes over it he hits the block?
I more like need to understand how this works. the player is not drawn in the tilemap, but over it, so I would need to like correlate the x and y to be checking if it is hitting a 1 or 2? if anyone can give an insight on how I would go about this, I have been stuck on it for pretty long.
http://jsfiddle.net/tzquvmey/1/

```
var mapArray = [
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,    1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,1,2,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,    1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,    1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,    1],
];
```

later in the code

```
for(i=0;i<mapArray.length;i++){
        for(j=0;j<mapArray[i].length;j++){
            if(mapArray[i][j]==0){
                context.drawImage(tile1, j*tileWidth,i*tileHeight,tileWidth,tileHeight);    
            }
            if(mapArray[i][j]==1){
                context.drawImage(tile2, j*tileWidth,i*tileHeight,tileWidth,tileHeight);    
            }
                    if(mapArray[i][j]==2){
                context.drawImage(tile3, j*tileWidth,i*tileHeight,tileWidth,tileHeight);    
            }
                    if(mapArray[i][j]==3){
                context.drawImage(tile4, j*tileWidth,i*tileHeight,tileWidth,tileHeight);    
            }
        }
    }
    context.drawImage(player,x,y,tileWidth,tileHeight);
}
```

later in the code

```
    if(mapArray[xpos][ypos]) {
    //COLLISION
        moveUp = 0;aaaaa
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

look up 2d collision detection, but the basic idea (which I copy pasted from [here](http://blog.sklambert.com/html5-canvas-game-2d-collision-detection/)) is:

```
if (object1.x < object2.x + object2.width  && object1.x + object1.width  > object2.x &&
        object1.y < object2.y + object2.height && object1.y + object1.height > object2.y) {
}
```

that's the most obvious way to do it.  if object 1's leftmost is less than object 2's rightmost, and the other 3 up/down right/left, down/up.

you're programming it with a map array, so you can multiply the tile height by the tile position to get their edges.